# Is it possible to record all the SQL executed by a session?

Tags: oracle

There is a web application which is connected to my Oracle database server via JDBC.

When a user does some actions on that web application, I want to know what SQL statements were submitted to database. Is this possible?

Comment: You can enable a database trace on session level. Maybe an overkill but it provides the information you are looking for.

Comment: Are you using connection pooling? If so you might need to track the SQL from the application layer not from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need auditing. Check the audit_trail parameter.

```
show parameter audit_trail
```

A null value means auditing is turned off. You need DB_EXTENDED to capture bind variables and sql statements.

```
alter system set audit_trail = db,extended scope=spfile;
```

You will need to re-start your database before auditing begins.
This will enable the columns `SQL_BIND` and `SQL_TEXT`.

To audit a users' session do this:

```
SQL> AUDIT session BY scott;
```

The `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` will have the audited records. The `SQL_TEXT` column will contain the sql statement the user ran.

Careful, your audit logs may fill up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all SQLs that were executed in the `sys.v$sqltext` view. Together with the `sys.v$session` view you can see who executed it. Is this what you are looking for?

Otherwise check to see if you can get the information from the application. See if you can change the log level for the classes that access the database.